# Detecting if client has disconnected

Tags: python, web-applications, webapp2

I am developing a web-application on GAE using `webapp2` web framework. It is a two player game with multiple instances of the game being played simultaneously. The server acts as the path to communicate game playing data between the two computers and also to validate it. **The clients communicate to the server by a HTTP request only.**

To do this, I will make a table in which I store the IP address, userId (by using cookies), and username (if the user has signed up) of both the users and the address to the game instance they are playing.

Until and unless the game finishes (either player wins) I would not remove the entry in the table, but I realized, what if one(or both) of the players disconnects before the game ends or there is a network error causing one(or both) of the players to quit.

**How would I come to know that the game is no longer active, so that I can remove the entry from the table and also notify the player still waiting for the opponent to move?**

Comment: have a certain process for a keepalive. http is stateless.

Comment: @DanielA.White I do not understand. Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- add a `last_action = DateTimeProperty(auto_now=true)` in your user model
- add a `ended = DateTimeProperty()` in your game model
- create a method that search all users with a `last_action < now - x minutes`, and set to now the `ended` property of all games with this users
- create a method that delete all games ended since y minutes
- run this methods periodically via tasks and a [cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron)

But if your clients can execute javascript, you better have a look at the [channel service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/).

Comment: Thank you @greg. I need to ask you this: 
Having received no answers earlier, I decided upon making the client (the browser) to poll the server every couple of seconds via a `XMLHttpRequest`. In that, if the other player has made a move, the server would respond with the move else just return a status message on the lines of 'Seen'. And mark the client is present. If the client misses 10 or so polls it would be considered disconnected. 
Is there a loophole in this approach? Is it better or worse? Why.

Comment: With your approach, if the two players are disconnected (no new poll), your game won't be ended.

Comment: Yes I wish to run another process to clean up the database from time to time, and I was wondering as to how to do that.

Comment: Set a cron every hour that get and delete games where last move (or poll) was there more than x minutes. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron